# Found Unit, required Int

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala code:

```
object Solution {

    def getBestSolution(sumList: List[Int]): Int = {
        return 0
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val t = readInt()

        (0 until t).foreach({
            val n = readInt()
            val a = readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt).toList
            val sumList = a.scanLeft(0)(_ + _).tail.toList
            //println(classOf[sumList])
            println(sumList)
            println(getBestSolution(sumList)) 
        })
    }

}
```

For it, I am getting this error:

```
file.scala:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int => ?
            println(getBestSolution(sumList))
                   ^
one error found
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument you are passing to `foreach` is the result of executing the code block (which is a `Unit`), not a function. 
Remove the outer parentheses (they do not really hurt anything, but are unnecessary and look ugly), and add `_ =>` in the beginning:

```
(0 to t).foreach { _ => 
   ...
   println(getBestSolution(sumList))
}
```

This is the proper syntax for creating an unnamed function. The stuff before `=>` is the parameter list that the function accepts. In your case, you can just put an underscore there, because you do not need the value of the parameter. Or you could give it a name if you needed to do something with it, e.g.: `(0 to t).foreach { x => println(x*x) }`

Answer (score 1):

you could have done it with simple `for` comprehension too instead of `foreach`

```
  for(x <- 0 to t){
    val n = readInt()
    val a = readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt).toList
    val sumList = a.scanLeft(0)(_ + _).tail.toList
    //println(classOf[sumList])
    println(sumList)
    println(getBestSolution(sumList))
  }
```

To sum up, [Programming in Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531644) book has pointed that `Scala provides the for comprehension, which provides syntactically pleasing nesting of map, flatMap, and filter ... The for comprehension is not a looping construct, but is a syntactic construct the compiler reduces to map, flatMap, and filter.`

Comment: Like your own quote says, this is not a "for loop" (and it's not "imperative style" either), but just another way to write `map`

Comment: @Dima, foreach and map requires conversion functions to be passed in them like Int => Unit or String => Int etc. But for loop doesn't require such cases. Thats why I call it imperative. You can read [this](https://apicrazy.com/2014/04/30/loops-in-scala-imperative-tailrecursive/) and [this](https://dzone.com/articles/scala-loops) they all call for loop as imperative

Comment: 'for loop' is imperative. `For comprehension` is _not_. There are no for-loops in scala. Only comprehensions. Your last two links refer to them as loops incorrectly.

Comment: Ok then I shall remove that paragraph as a whole. :) Its seems that I had been understanding and reading wrong. Thanks. Let me know if there are still errors after the edit.

Comment: You're still calling it a for loop. See your first line. It's also `0 until t`.